# Intercepting with Scapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, scapy, man-in-the-middle

I try to develop a MITM attack tool, first tried arp poisoning, then sniffing and filter specific packet (both of them with scapy)
if there is a match with my filter I need to alter it on the fly so, create a copy of this packet then manipulate TCP data and send it.
But the last step doesn't work. Does it correct manipulate for copying packet?

```
    from netfilterqueue import NetfilterQueue
    from scapy.all import *
    from scapy.error import Scapy_Exception
    import os
    import sys
    import threading
    import signal

    def Inspector (packet):
        if packet[TCP].payload :
            tcp_data = str(packet[TCP].payload)

            if 'Open' in tcp_data:
                packet_data = tcp_data.split('(')
                a= copy.deepcopy(packet)                                                        # First Copy The packet
                packet.drop()                                                                           # Second Drop it
                if 'Up' in tcp_data :
                    payload_O = packet_data[0] + '(' + 'Down//inject'
                    a[TCP].data = payload_O
                    send(a)
            else :
                packet.accept()

    def  main():
        try:
            print '[*] Starting Queue '
            nfqueue.run_socket()
            sniff(filter="tcp port 2626", prn=inspector, store=0)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to intercept a packet using scapy. What your code might do is send another packet following the original one.

The best way to create a MITM tool is by ARP poisoning. You can have a look at scapy tutorials such as in:

- [The scapy official doc](http://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [This good tutorial at medium.com](https://medium.com/@ismailakkila/black-hat-python-arp-cache-poisoning-with-scapy-7cb1d8b9d242)

Of course, your tool will only be used in a security purpose, as you know that such pratice is illegal